# Why is vector calculus so much more important in classical electrodynamics than in classical mechanics?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, vector-fields

In this question "vector calculus" refers to the integration and differentiation of vector fields.

Why is vector calculus so much more important in classical electrodynamics than in classical mechanics?

I'm not looking for answers such as "there are these formulas which are prominent in electrodynamics and those formulas use vector calculus", because my question essentially is: what is fundamental about electrodynamics compared to mechanics that would require such formulas to appear in it in the first place?

In other words, what fundamental physical fact that separates the forces of electrodynamics from those of mechanics makes it likely that in the formulas of the electrodynamical model vector calculus will make an appearance?

Comment: I think this may be a bit opinion-based. You'll find that an important metric is the number of degrees of freedom. For example, many coupled harmonic oscillators will yield motion well-described by partial differential equations of multivariable calculus. Stress and strain, which I often imagine as being in the field of classical mechanics, give rise to equations of motion that are tensorial in nature. So I think you'll find that classical mechanics with many d.o.f. is closer to electrodynamics than you think! Indeed, classical electrodynamics is a classical field theory (infinite d.o.f.)

Comment: Who says vectors are not important in classical mechanics? Velocity, momentum, angular momentum, etc. are all vector quantities.

Comment: @Avantgarde Vector calculus in the sense of "differentiation and integration of vector fields". On the first page of my electrodynamics book there is a review of vector calculus. On the first page of the mechanics book by the same author there is no such review. I'm looking for the essence of this fact. I'm not saying vectors are not important in mechanics.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think this is the only commonly used meaning of that term, "vector calculus"? But I can edit it in if you think this is helpful.

Comment: The answer is "It's not.", but you don't get to the applications of vector calculus in classical mechanics at the high school level. Once you transition to the university level, it becomes a very important tool.

Comment: $v \times B$  and $I \times \omega$ are pretty common in intro E&M and mechanics...

Comment: Given the many downvotes I figure this is not considered a good question in this site, probably because it doesn't seem to be well researched. That might be somewhat true, but on this site I could not find any answer to my question, and doesn't that in itself make it a good question? My question is from the point of view of a layman. The answers I was given by the experts pointed me in the right direction for further learning and so the question was definitely beneficial to me. Thanks for all the answers (and comments).

Comment: Yes, the downvotes are *probably* due to people assuming that your question's premise (about the importance of vector calculus) indicates a lack of prior research. I suppose you could phrase that premise as a question rather than as a declaration, but that may be tricky to do without invalidating the existing answers.

Comment: @PM2Ring I will leave the question as is, to not invalidate existing answers. Perhaps I should have been clearer that I'm speaking of beginning physics courses, and maybe I should have said 'elementary classical mechanincs' rather than 'classical mechanics' and so on, then surely the premise of the question would have been correct. Googling "is vector calculus needed in classical mechanics?", etc, does not seem to bring up any relevant results, hence I was not aware of any distinction, and I feel that given my non-expertise in the subject my question was a fair one. Thanks again for the tips.

Answer (score 4):

Vector calculus is necessary when describing the dynamics of fields, which are described mathematically as functions of several variables (usually spatial coordinates and time). The electric and magnetic fields are typically the first example of dynamical fields that you encounter during your physics education. In classical particle mechanics, the fundamental dynamical variables are the particle's position and momentum, which are functions of only one variable (i.e. time) and so vector calculus is not necessary.

Vector calculus does *appear* in classical particle mechanics in the sense that particles often interact with background fields, but because those fields typically don't evolve with time it is often not necessary to do any intensive vector calculus with them, as you would if you had to study their evolution equations.

With that being said, the premise of the question is not necessarily true from a more advanced perspective. [Continuum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics) (e.g. fluid dynamics or [elastodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity)) falls under the general heading of classical mechanics, but is also fundamentally a theory of fields and requires quite a lot of vector and tensor calculus. [Classical statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics) and thermodynamics also make use of vector calculus in a generalized sense, where the "fields" in question are no longer necessarily functions of spatial coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Classical electrodynamics is a field theory. It describes the electric and magnetic fields as vector fields. Thus, vector calculus is so important in classical electrodynamics.

Vector calculus is needed to describe any theory involving fields. Representing some quantity as a field may help to develop intuition. Thus, vector calculus can also be used in classical mechanics if using a "field interpretation" is more intuitive than the alternatives for that particular problem. Example- fluid mechanics; Cartan's theory of gravity.

Comment: Thanks. In a sense this seems circular to me. Why is it a field theory and classical mechanics is not? Maybe that is basically my question.
Maybe it is more of a philosophical question than a physical one, so I'm not sure it has a good answer.

Comment: Cartan theory is a field theory for Newtonian gravity. We can just define a quantity, express it as a vector field and use it to perform calculations. It is a matter of interpretation and intuition.

Answer (score 3):

No, when it comes to fluids, say, or if you are interested in the internal motion of extended objects, or if you are interested in the general behaviour of a family of systems i.e. all the different energies, not just the single one specific to one instantiation thereof, vector calculus also becomes important to classical mechanics.

It is just that we are often just trying to teach the basics in classical mechanics, and exploiting conservation of momentum and energy and angular momentum and assuming rigid bodies, that the complicated equations simplify.

It is also the case that in electrodynamics we care about the fields in the vacuum of space, where the fields are not constant. In the gravitational case we often just do it with the gravitational potential and rarely need the full blown gravitational field. The electrostatic potential came from people having already studied the gravitational potential and field cases, and they realised those same ideas applied to electrostatics too.